# Creating X amount of new database rows using input X from a form in Rails with auto-incrementing name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am working on my first rails app in which hotel owners can add types of rooms (premium, budget, single rooms, double rooms etc.) incl.  the # of rooms of that type (room_count).

I am currently working with 3 tables,

(i) hotels table, where the user can create a new hotel,

(ii) accommodation_categories table, where the user can enter a new type of rooms incl. room_count &

(iii) an accommodations table, with the individual rooms per type.

My question is how to use the room_count input of the accommodation_categories table (obtained via a form) can be used to automatically create these room records in my accommodations table

e.g. how to translate the accommodation_category table input room_count into room_count*records of accommodations?

~ I am really sorry if this explanation is too elaborate, but I am not sure how else to explain it given that my technical vocabulary is rather limited ~

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :hotels do
    resources :accommodation_categories do
      resources :accommodations
  end
end
```

hotel.rb

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accommodation_categories, dependent: :destroy
end
```

accommodation_category.rb

```
class AccommodationCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  has_many :accommodations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

accommodation.rb

```
class Accommodation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :accommodation_category
end
```

accommodation_categories_controller.rb

```
def new
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @accommodation_category = AccommodationCategory.new
  end

  def create
    @accommodation_category = AccommodationCategory.new(accommodation_category_params)
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @accommodation_category.hotel = @hotel
    @accommodation_category.save
    redirect_to hotel_accommodation_categories_path
  end
```

views/accommodation_categories/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @accommodation_category] do |f|%>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :room_count %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Check out nested attributes and nested forms. Also the cocoon gem is a good gem to make the flow on the view nice

Comment: Thank you Mike!:) I never used the cocoon gem, but from the documentation it indeed seems to be quite useful, when creating new records in nested attributes. Key will now be to figure out how to link the number of accommodations entered into actual accommodations.

Comment: I think cocoon has an index number of how many nested records have been intialized. I'm not sure but I'm pretty sure there's something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I indeed used the cocoon gem with which you can create multiple nested objects via one form. It works perfectly.

To create multiple objects without details you can use controller lines such as:

```
@accommodation_category[:accommodation_count].times {@accommodation_category.accommodations.build}
```